# c# StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries not work

Tags: c#

I want to split the namelist with spaces and remove the spaces but the space is not deleted.Also, random numbers always sound the same like in the photo.

form1.cs button click codes

```
            string[] cells;
            char[] ayraclar = { ' ' };
            foreach (string row in createdMailList.Items)
            {
                cells = row.Split(ayraclar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string[] isimler = new string[cells.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] chars = new string[cells[i].Length];
                    isimler[i] = cells[i].ToString();
                    listBox1.Items.Add(helper.anlamliMail(isimler));          

                }
            }
```

helper.cs class codes

```
    public static string anlamliMail(string[] items)
    {
        string kelime ="";
        var rnd = new Random();
        
        foreach (var row in items)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {
                kelime = items[rnd.Next(0, items.Length)] + rnd.Next(0, 9999);
            }
        }
        
        return kelime + "@yahoo.com";

    }
```

createdMailList content
[image]

result : [image]

I split the list of names with spaces, but the space is coming. that's why there are only numbers of mails

Comment: Hi Muhamment, Can you create Minimal reproducible example? That will help us to solve your problem

Comment: I would post the random number question separately.

Comment: I don't understand, how should I do

Comment: What do you mean "the space is not deleted"?  What are you basing that on with the material you have provided us?

Comment: post your input data. Post explanation, what your method does

Comment: I want to convert the list of names to mail

Comment: I split the list of names with spaces, but the space is coming. that's why there are only numbers of mails

Comment: Please supply a [mcve], preferably as a https://dotnetfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a random object once only , not each time when you call anlamliMail

```
               var rnd = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++)
                   isimler[i] = cells[i].ToString();
           
               foreach (var item in isimler)
                   listBox1.Items.Add(helper.anlamliMail(rnd,isimler));
```

and fix anlamliMai

```
public static string anlamliMail(Random rnd, string[] items)
    {
             string kelime ="";
              do
               {
               kelime =  items[rnd.Next(0, items.Length);
               }
               while (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(kelime));

        return kelime + rnd.Next(0, 9999).ToString() + "@yahoo.com";

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this method. problem solved thanks to you